# Controling do while loop with string

Tags: string, loops, while-loop

Hi folks this is my question for example i have 3 articles and user can chose any one of them or all of them. In the beginning i ask a user, "do you want to choose some articles?" and if he types yes than we start a `while` or `do while` loop that adds prices of all chosen articles and adds them to the total value,
for example article one price is 20 and article 3 price is 40 it should write you have chosen articles one and article three and total price is 60. And when user ends with his choosing he types no and the loop ends.

The real question is my `do while` loop is always endless i don't know how to stop the loop with a String. This my 10th version of code, i tried everything but really can't solve this problem.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner tastatura = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Artikal 1\nArtikal 2\nArtikal 3");

    System.out.println("Do you want to chose a new article");
    String choiseString = tastatura.nextLine();

    do {
        System.out.println("Chose article ");
        int choise = tastatura.nextInt();
        switch (choise) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Artikal 1 ");
                int price = 10;
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Artikal 2 ");
               price= 20;
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Artikal 3");
               price = 30;
                break;
        }

    } while (choiseString.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") );

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue is that you never give the opportunity for the user to change the value of choiseString.

You allow the user to set the value before the loop begins, but once inside the loop it doesn't change.

Your while loop could instead do something like:

```
do {
  System.out.println("Do you wish to continue?");
  choiseString = tastatura.nextLine();

  System.out.println("Chose article ");
  int choise = tastatura.nextInt();
  //rest of your logic here

} while (choiseString.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") );
```

In this case it would then ask for 1 more choice and then exit the loop (although I haven't tested this code).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use a boolean.

This way you will only need to check for true or false, or 1/0.

But the important part is to in some point inside the loop, set that variable to true or false, because if you don't do that, the loop will be an infinite loop.

Once you set the variable to false or true in some point inside the loop, everything will goes fine ;)

I hope this helps